# how to store data in App even After User Logout and Close the App. in react native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, local-storage, asyncstorage

Is it possible To store some data in App. Even after User logout it and close it from recent Apps.
if yes then How.
I heard About redux and redux persist. But I am not able to store data in app when I logout and close my app from recent app. So I dont know if I cant execute it properly.
is redux and redux persist really store data even after app logout and close from recent app ??
or is there another method or library for that..

Answer (score 0):

I Build an app and used [Expo.Sqlite](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/) as a data store.

I even build an ORM for it if you are interested I could post it here to.

Comment: Yes But I want It in React natiev not expo

Comment: Expo is a library for react-native my friend. You could also use any other Sqlite library but expo is very easy to use. You only need to use their library and not expo it self

Comment: can I use Expo.Sqlite in core react native app. because I heard That expo library cant work in core react native. correct if I am wrong. Because I have only 6 month in react native

Comment: Well that I do not know if its possible or not, But it should be. Where did you read that it is not ? You could still use Other Sqlite library. But the setup almost the same so using expo or other library there will still be a small native changes. When you say core is it .Net core?

Comment: because I cant use expo Icons library for my react natiive. app so that why I think expo library does not support for react native.

Comment: read the instructions https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-sqlite you have to install `react-native-unimodules` before any other expo libray. choose bare installations

Comment: OK I will try This. But do You know that redux or redux persist is stored data in app even after app logout and close from recent apps.

Comment: Yes it is but you have to create the project with expo.cli or npx :) here is the instructions https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-use-redux-persist-in-react-native-with-asyncstorage/ I will still recommend sqlite its a lot easier and less code i think.